# Export leaflet map to geojson

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, geojson

Is it possible to export geojson from leaflet to save the map state?

I want to store the markers, zoom & map center to load it later.

There is plenty of ways to load geojson on leaflet, but I can't figure out any option to export the map to geojson...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no "out-of-the-box" option to export all the markers on the map to GeoJSON but it's something you can do easily do yourself. Leaflet's `L.Marker` has a `toGeoJSON` method:

> Returns a GeoJSON representation of the marker (GeoJSON Point Feature).

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-togeojson

For example:

```
// Create a marker
var marker = new L.Marker([0, 0]);
// Get the GeoJSON object
var geojson = marker.toGeoJSON();
// Log to console
console.log(geojson);
```

Will output to your console:

```
{
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties":{},
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[0,0]
    }
}
```

If you want to store all the markers added to your map in a GeoJSON collection, you could do something like this:

```
// Adding some markers to the map
var markerA = new L.Marker([0, 0]).addTo(map),
    markerB = new L.Marker([1, 1]).addTo(map),
    markerC = new L.Marker([2, 2]).addTo(map),
    markerD = new L.Marker([3, 3]).addTo(map);

// Create an empty GeoJSON collection
var collection = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": []
};

// Iterate the layers of the map
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    // Check if layer is a marker
    if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
        // Create GeoJSON object from marker
        var geojson = layer.toGeoJSON();
        // Push GeoJSON object to collection
        collection.features.push(geojson);
    }
});

// Log GeoJSON collection to console
console.log(collection);
```

Will output to your console:

```
{
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[{
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{},
        "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[0,0]
        }
    },{
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{},
        "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[1,1]
        }
    },{
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{},
        "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[2,2]
        }
    },{
        "type":"Feature",
        "properties":{},
        "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[3,3]
        }
    }]
}
```

***Edit***: However, as the QP found out, if you're able to put your markers into a `L.LayerGroup`, `L.FeatureGroup` or `L.GeoJSON` layer you can just use it's `toGeoJSON` method which returns a GeoJSON featurecollection:

> Returns a GeoJSON representation of the layer group (GeoJSON FeatureCollection).

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-togeojson

If you want to store the map's current bounds (center and zoom) you could simply add it to the collection doing this:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();

var collection = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "bbox": [[
        bounds.getSouthWest().lng,
        bounds.getSouthWest().lat
    ], [
        bounds.getNorthEast().lng,
        bounds.getNorthEast().lat
    ]],
    "features": []
};
```

You can later restore it by using the bbox member in conjunction with `L.Map`'s `setBounds` method. That's it. You could send it to the server or download it via dataurl whatever you like. Hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! It helped me finding a simplier solution :))

Comment: I was using a similar solution but found that when i dumped the output of toGeoJson() to an elements innerhtml all I would get is [object][object].

My solution was to use: JSON.stringify(collection.toGeoJSON());

Answer (score 6):

I've found a simplier solution based on iH8's answer and a colleague's help.

First, create a `FeatureGroup` layer and add it to the map:

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);
```

Then add the marker (or other elements) to the layer:

```
var marker = new L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(drawnItems);
```

And export everything when you want to :

```
var collection = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
var bounds = map.getBounds();

collection.bbox = [[
    bounds.getSouthWest().lng,
    bounds.getSouthWest().lat,
    bounds.getNorthEast().lng,
    bounds.getNorthEast().lat
]];

// Do what you want with this:
console.log(collection);
```