# I would like to convert all feature collections to geometry collections in Leaflet

Tags: python, json, leaflet, gis, geojson

For example, the toGeoJSON function returns something like this here:

```
var geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Coors Field",
        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
    }
};
```

but I would like to exclusively use a GeometryCollection, not a FeatureCollection as described here. Is there any way I could do that?

For more information, I would like to replicate the behavior described in the check-marked answer in [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125036/export-leaflet-map-to-geojson), but I would like to use GeometryCollections instead. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution. In order to persist it as a GeometryCollection, I used the serializer described in the `djang_rest_gis` framework. As a result, I was able to turn my polygon into a GEOSGeomtry object, and serialize that.